# Calabash iOS finding objects not on screen

Tags: calabash-ios

I'm using xamarin calabash-sandbox, (calabash-ios 0.20.4) to test an app on an iOS simulator.  When the app is on screen, query("label", :text) finds the expected objects e.g.

`[0] "Learn More",
[1] "Skip"`

When I press the app's Learn More button, Safari pops up and displays the expected webpage.  However, the query above returns the same results, even though the app is no longer visible.  According to the documentation, calabash should only find visible objects.

In fact, query finds whatever objects are on the app screen, no matter how you take the app off screen e.g. you can hit the home button or bring up another app and query still finds the same objects.  Is this a bug, or is there some way to limit calabash to only finding visible objects?

FYI, the above works correctly on calabash-android

Answer (score 0):

```
# Queries your application - the Application Under Test
query("label", :text)
```

The Safari Web View Controller is not part of your application.  You can try to interact with the Safari Web View Controller using DeviceAgent queries and gestures

```
# Return a list of visible views
device_agent.query({ }) 

# Return a list of all views
device_agent.query({all: true})
```

The DeviceAgent API (including example queries) is [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/develop/calabash-cucumber/lib/calabash-cucumber/device_agent.rb#L49).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm sorry if I wasn't clear - I wasn't trying to query Safari, I was trying to confirm that my app was no longer visible.  To do that I used the same query as before, which should not return any results since my app is not on screen (Safari is on screen instead). However, it returned the same results as if my app were on the screen, and that's the problem.  I may be misunderstanding something but if my app is not visible, I expected the query to return nothing.

Comment: I understand your question now.   I am not sure the LPServer could ever know that a SafariWebView is showing.  If you want us to investigate this, please open an issue on calabash-ios-server.  As a proxy for "my app is not visible", I suggest to try asking if the Safari WebView _is_ visible.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, I'll pursue that for the moment.  Rather than have the LPServer know that SafariWebView is showing, it seems it ought to know that it's own view isn't showing.  The docs clearly state that it only returns visible views by default, so what does that really mean?

Comment: I've opened this issue on calabash-ios-server: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios-server/issues/377

Comment: I worked around this on iOS by using device_agent.query({ }) as the implementation for the step "my app is not visible".  This query returns [] when Safari is on screen and my app is running off screen, which is what's needed.  This workaround takes 50 seconds to execute on my system.  The device api (per link given above) also states "This API is work in progress.  There are several methods that are experimental and several methods that will probably removed soon." so support for this workaround isn't guaranteed.  Hopefully the issue I opened (see above) will be resolved for a permanent fix.